# Do you name classes and ids as headless camel case?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a Cust table in a database, it begins with an uppercase C.

If I have a CustName field in a Cust table, it begins with an uppercase C.

So I want to name my identifier

```
id="CustName"
```

or my class:

```
class="CustClass"
```

but I'm thinking that maybe I should identify them as

```
id="custName"
```

and

```
class="custClass"
```

It didn't seem to matter until I started referring to these identifiers and classes in JavaScript. At that point it seemed like they should be in headlessCamelCase.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here? Do you want to poll the community or know about javascript conventions more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939909/html-naming-conventions-for-id-class-and-to-include-element-type-prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One popular convention for ids and class names is to use hyphens, like this: `id="cust-name"`. 
This stems from the fact that CSS selectors are case-insensitive.

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap uses the same convention and I've got a habit to follow it too. Pointing out that CSS selectors are case-insensitive is very important. That is way camel case doesn't make a lot of sense. If it is "custName" you can also address it as "Custname" or "custname". +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think generally it depends on your coding team and practices, however convention seems to be that you are less likely to run into errors if you use all lowercase or lowercase with underscores in classes and ids due to case sensitivity.

In my opinion...
**for classes and IDs:** all lowercase > under_scores >  InitialCaps > camelCase because if you are calling selectors in javascript or php it's easier to identify quickly that it's a class or id and not some variable, function or constructor, in addition to avoiding errors in mixing case when targeting the class.

but...
**for server side programming:** camelCase > under_scores > InitialCaps.